# How do I send a message from an app made in Construct 2 to my email?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, email, construct-2

I.m working on an app made with Scirras Construct 2 Engine. The engine is pretty straightforward using HTML5 and Javascript.

I'm trying to learn how to send a message from my Construct 2 app to my email.
I want this feature because I'm trying to set up a list of people who want to join a newsletter.
I would rather people be able to sign up through my app rather than go to a website.

How hard would this be to set up and is it even possible to do without touching complex code?

Comment: What have you done on your own?

Comment: @TomZych I have all of the stuff in place to actually set it up,I just dont understand how.Everything i have learned has been self taught without school,I have had alot of help from the scirra community along the way and i feel great knowing what i know as of now.

Comment: An app? What platform? Or is it a web app?

Answer (score 0):

You can run a mail server that receives your app information and send the emails or you could create a database on a remote server which function is to store the information received by your app.

The database/remote server thing is not difficult with python flask + sqlalchemy but it dependes a lot on your previous knowledge.

This is a long list so I will point out resources I found. If i'd write them here, it'd take pages and pages.

Flask: http://flask.pocoo.org/

SQLAlchemy in Flask: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/sqlalchemy/

The remote server could be host as an EC2 instance on Amazon Web Services: http://aws.amazon.com/

Construct 2 on AJAX: https://www.scirra.com/manual/107/ajax

A good tutorial on a RESTful API(flask example):http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask